# email sender backend with angularjs frontend

Tags: angularjs, backend

If I was to make a page that sends emails from clients, what should i use for backend.  Of course, I mean what's the best & the easiest way?

I thought about slim php framework or similar stuff.

But can this be done easily with a node.js or any other cloud solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> thought about slim php framework

Is plain old PHP just too easy? It's between 1 and 5 lines of code without a framework depending on the security model.

> can this be done easily with a node.js or any other cloud solutions?

Oh dear. You've been sitting too close to the sales people. node.js is not a "cloud solution". Yes node.js is quite capable of doing this, as is ASP, Java, Python, .NET, Perl, bash..... IMHO it's more difficult with node.js than with PHP - since you need to configure the node.js as a webserver and add libraries to support SMTP.

Comment: great, thanks for your honesty.  so if i use just plain php, should i just echo a back a json to angular to know that email is sent?

Comment: did this with slim framework, and it work just great, at the end, it's still few lines of code, and you get to keep your routing in line.

Answer (score 2):

My recomendation is implement the mail funcionality out from client service.

If you have an API backend consumed in your front-end, you should implement at this API.If you dont have right now a backend, create a simple nodejs backend for that functionallity, this will provide you high scalability and security for you email account.

I dont recommend you to use php for that. Ofcurse that you can do it, but if you do "magic things" do them right.